# List gaps between smallest and the biggest time interval

Tags: php, date, intervals

I had an php interview question and I am curious about the solution, maybe you can help me.

The problem sound like that :

There are many time intervals in this format 'ZZ-LL-AAAA'. I want to know if there are gaps between the smallest date and the biggest date from all the intervals.
List the gaps.

some example :

```
1) 01.01.2000 - 31.01.2000 
2) 01.03.2000 - 31.03.2000 
3) 15.01.2000 - 15.02.2000 
gaps it will be 16.02.2000 - 28.02.2000 (or 29, if is bisect year)
```

Comment: time intervals or date intervals? what do you mean by gaps between smallest date and biggest date

Comment: Sounds like you're a codility solutions seeker https://www.martinkysel.com/codility-solutions/

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki That was my question too but they didn't want to tell me. I will send an e-mail and ask them for details

Comment: I got it, lets say you have a set of 3 from and to dates like 1-jan-2017 to 3-jan-2017, 4-jan-2017 to 6-jan-2017 and 7-jan-2017 to 9-jan-2017. They according to your question we have to find if there are any gaps between 1-jan-2017 to 9-jan-2017. In the current scenario there are no gaps. But if we change the last pair from 8-jan-2017 to 9-jan-2017 then we have one day gap.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki I got their answer:         1) 01.01.2000 - 31.01.2000
2) 01.03.2000 - 31.03.2000
3) 15.01.2000 - 15.02.2000

gaps it will be 16.02.2000 - 28.02.2000 (or 29, if is bisect year)